# Getting an error when installing gcc on CentOS without root permission, configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: python, linux, gcc, centos7

I am trying to install gcc-6.3.0 from a tar.gz source on CentOS without root permission. When I run `../gcc-6.3.0/configure`, I get the following error.

```
configure: error: in `/home/build-gcc':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I had a look on the similar topics on stackoverflow and tried the solutions, but still get the error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Example gcc-6.3.0 configuring https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rSliR_bgje_LYzVgvsrQEp99Nx2d_vf9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got a chicken-and-egg issue here: gcc is written in C, so you need a C compiler to compile your compiler

Install another compiler and use it to build the one you want

Optionally re-building with the version you built for potentially-greater compatibility!

Comment: Exactly! Would you elaborate more on your answer? Which compiler can I use to install gcc?

Comment: Whomever administrates the system should be able to do this for you! If they don't agree, they may be actively preventing this use and you should understand why! If you have some shared, restricted access, but still must do this, it's probably better to compile it on another system and bring it over, otherwise this is a very open-ended problem dependent on your system (chroot, bringing in a simpler compiler, containers..)